# Page Shadow Effect: Catch the Focus Out Event

Tags: jquery

Here is what I am thinking:

When a user browses some other page, or uses different application, or to say straight is not actively interacting with the webpage I want to catch this as a event and trigger a fadeIn() function. In this particular case only, I want to fill the page with shadow, which fades out once the user is back.

The question is , How to catch this event, and execute a function?

Created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wHKyZ/) but I want the shadow to fade in, when the mouseout event triggers in window, but if I do so, when I come back in the body, the window start pulsating.

Comment: Let me just say, that this is completely unnecessary and not user friendly. Imagine someone wanting to copy and paste something into your app. Instead of clicking on a textbox on your site they now require another click to activate your app again.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to trigger the focus event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy. Just use the `blur` and `focus` events on window. You can do whatever you want to show/hide your page shadow in the callbacks. Personally, I'd recommend the [BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

```
$(function()
{
    var $body = $('body');
    $(window).focus(function () { $body.removeClass('fade'); })
             .blur(function () { $body.addClass('fade'); });
});?
```

**Working example:** http://jsbin.com/idipo5/2 (tested in Chrome) (be forewarned, it's really ugly)

---

**Edit:**  I'm pretty this what you're going for. Note how it doesn't unmask if the window is moused-over but doesn't have focus. If you do want it to unmask in this case, you can remove the `focused` flag and its checks.

**Tested in Chrome and FF** (IE is a miserable piece of not-worth-my-time)**:**

> http://jsbin.com/ufido3

Posting the JS code below, since I'm not sure how long JSBin keeps your stuff around.

---

```
$(function ()
{
  var $modal = $('#modal'),
      masked = false,
      focused = true;

  function mask()
  {
    if (!masked)
    {
      $modal.fadeIn('fast');
      masked = true;
    }
  }

  function unmask()
  {
    if (masked && focused)
    {
      $modal.fadeOut('fast');
      masked = false;
    }
  }

  $('html').hover(unmask, mask).focus(function (e)
  {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('html')) unmask();
  }).blur(function (e)
  {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('html')) mask();
  });

  $(window).focus(function ()
  {
    focused = true;
    unmask();
  }).blur(function ()
  {
    focused = false;
    mask();
  });
});
```

Comment: However BLOCKUI plugin was pretty sleek :D

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? Your demo seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Well, instead of only blur, I want this effect to work in mouseout also, try changing the blur to mouseout, we will see whats wrong.

Comment: See my update. I'm not that big a fan of the mask-on-mouseleave, but the mask-on-window-blur is nifty.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly What I was trying to build. Thank u so much